# How to Increase Size of Smart Object in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I purchased a dispenser bottle mockup, which uses a smart object as the label layer to make it easier to place the design. I am needing to increase the size of the label but am finding that when I can only scale the label down in size, not larger. It seems to have some sort of set maximum size. I need the label to cover more of the bottle, as my design is covers most of the bottle, so I need to increase the label size. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my first time working with smart layers. I am going to try a workaround by simply creating a new smart layer with larger dimensions since it appears i can scale down but not up and deleting the original smart layer. I'll report back if that works.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change the area that the smart object covers then transform the smart object layer. If you want to change the resolution/image size within the smart object then open the smart layer (which opens a new tab) and change the image size.

Comment: If there is a warp transform on the smart object, i.e. to wrap the label around the bottle, and you have edited the size of the smart object, you may have to apply a further transform in the main document to resize the label. Use CTRL+T (Command+T on Mac).

Answer (score 2):

Once you press cmd+T/ctrl+T to bring up the handles that allow for manual resizing, an option bar will appear at the top where you can type in numbers for Height and Width. See if that allows you to increase the size. I've never heard of a max size for any object within Photoshop. Maybe the computer needs a restart!